# Airflow insert into BigQuery if row doesn't exist or do not insert if exists

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I have this web scraping DAG which will run everyday. I will load this data to my staging table, the problem is running daily is needed because I don't know when new data is coming so I need to make sure it'll be available by tomorrow by least. The problem is I don't want to load the same data I scrap to the table. The web scrap is huge and so is the staging table. Is there any hooks or operator for this? Currently I do insert_all like this, so this will create duplicate in my staging table which I don't want. The function doesn't have option to replace/reject if exists

```
BIGQUERY_HOOK.insert_all(
            project_id=project_id,
            dataset_id=data_set,
            table_id=table,
            rows=data,
            fail_on_error=True,
            ignore_unknown_values=ignore_unknown_values,
        )
```